# If I set the pixels for a component , will it behave the same on every monitor?

Tags: html, css, pixel

Will the following `css` :

```
#search_bar {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left:475px;
  height:27px;
}
```

generate the same position of search bar on every mointor as in the following snapshot ?

[image]

Like units in percentage will show the size accordingly on every monitor,is it the same with pixels ? I mean I try to align the search box as visible in the snapshot in the center but I don't know if it will look the same on broader monitors than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither monitors nor screen resolution have anything to do with how your element will be positioned.  What matters is the width/height of the viewport (especially since desktop users don't always maximize their browser).  If the viewport is only 300px wide, not only will your element not be centered, it will be so far to the right that it will appear off screen!  If the viewport is 2000px wide, it will be woefully far to the left.

Here are 2 options for perfectly centering an element no matter what the viewport size is.

```
input.one {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}

input.two {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -150px; /* half of the element's width */
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bGMck/

Comment: I did this : `#search_bar {
 position:absolute;
 width: 300px;
 margin-left:475px;
 height:27px;
}` Is it okay ?

Comment: That's not any different than what you have in your question, and it will not be centered at every viewport.  Resize your browser and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you position an element in pixels, that element is said to be absolute positioned. That means users with a different-sized window may not see it centered on the screen.

You could use JavaScript to reposition centered elements like these on page load or a window resize:

```
function doResize() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('myCenterDiv');
    var ww = window.innerWidth;
    var elemWidth = elem.offsetWidth;
    elem.style.left = (ww - elemWidth) / 2;
}
window.onload = doResize;
window.onresize = doResize;
```

Or, you could do it the CSS way:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
body > #myCenterDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* This centers the element */
}
```

Comment: Or just do it properly with CSS. You shouldn't have to use JS for layout.

Comment: I didn't understand the word _off center_

Comment: It's not absolute positioned unless you set `position: absolute`. This is a very different thing than specifying width and margins in px.

Comment: can you please explain the `margin 0 auto` property ? If I include it,the search box shifts to the left from the center

Answer (score -1):

In older HTML versions there was a thing called `<center>` which is now not there. In order to center anything in HTML5, in the css write:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

This will center any object.

If you dont want it in the center then you may use **Javascript:**

```
var screen = screen.availWidth;
var gapPercent = 20;
var gap = gapPercent/screen;
document.getElementById('search_bar').style.margin-left = "gap + 'px'";
```

I dont know the exact code, please. Try the code and im sure if the document.get...... Thing is written properly then it would work- i havent used js for quite a time.